# What dos "get hitched" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

http://www.nytimes.com/2015/10/19/magazine/the-lost-history-of-gay-adult-adoption.html

> In May 2008, the California Supreme Court gave gay couples the right to marry. This was reversed in a matter of months, when voters adopted a constitutional amendment. But in the interim, on June 18 at 9:30 a.m., Faderman and Irwin got **hitched**. What they didn’t do, however, was vacate the adoption.

Comment: In the US, "getting hitched" has long been a slang term for "getting married".

Comment: A dictionary is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an idiomatic expression for getting married:

> > Hitch: To bind by marriage vows; unite in marriage; marry.

([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hitched))

Comment: But I don't recall ever seeing it used in the active, or even the prototypical passive (_was hitched_). It's nearly always in the form _get hitched_.